# Express-Session picks up expired cookie

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Using Node 8.11.3, Express 4.16.3, Express-Session 1.15.6

I create a session with a cookie with a very short expiry date:

```
var expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 1 * 60 * 1000) // 1 minute
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({ url: config.gmi.db.url }),
    secret: 'sdfsdfsdfsdf',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        expires: expiryDate      //TODO secure cookies when we go to HTTPS
    }
}));
```

I get 401 on routes as I should, but when I log out, then log back in, it seems like I am picking up the expired session:

```
LOGIN SESSION>>>>> {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":-1181398,"expires":"2018-07-10T17:43:19.339Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"username":"derek@sdf.com"}
POST /login 200 48578.580 ms - 2
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":-1234394,"expires":"2018-07-10T17:43:19.339Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}}
GET /tenants 401 3064.476 ms - 12
```

Here is my middleware for routes:

```
var auth = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.session));
    if (req.session && req.session.username)
        return next();
    else
        return res.sendStatus(401);
};
```

and my logout routine:

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        req.session.destroy();
        res.send("logout success!");
    });
```

my login simply sets the username:

```
req.session.username = req.body.username;
console.log("LOGIN SESSION>>>>>", JSON.stringify(req.session));
```

Shouldn't it create a new session with a new expires and originalMaxAge? There is no cookie on my browser either.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reset the max age and the expiry, as those are always associated with the user.

So my login looks like this

```
//find user in DB
//make sure password is good
if (req.session.cookie && req.session.cookie.originalMaxAge < 0) {
    var hour = 1 * 60 * 1000;
    req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + hour)
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = hour
}
req.session.username = req.body.username;
console.log("LOGIN SESSION>>>>>", JSON.stringify(req.session));
```

Here is some information on this:
https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookiemaxage-1